# MySQL equivalent of MSSQL CONVERT()

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have this fragment of MSSQL -

```
CONVERT(INT, HASHBYTES('MD5', {some_field}))
```

...and I'd really like a MySQL equivalent. I'm pretty sure the `HASHBYTES('MD5', ...)` bit is the same as MySQL's `MD5(...)` - it's the `CONVERT(INT, ...)` bit that's really puzzling me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the MySQL manual entry for the [`MD5()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5) function:

> The value is returned as a string of 32 hex digits, or `NULL` if the argument was `NULL`.

The MSSQL [`CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function which you quote above converts its `varbinary` argument to a signed 32-bit integer by truncating to the 4 lowest-order bytes.  This is a bit of a nuisance because MySQL arithmetic works to 64-bit precision.

We must therefore take the rightmost 8 digits of MySQL's hex representation (representing the 4 lowest-order bytes) and convert to decimal using MySQL's [`CONV()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) function, then sign-extend the result:

```
CONV(RIGHT(MD5('foo'),8), 16, 10) ^ 0x80000000 - 0x80000000
```

Comment: Sadly, that all seems to result in zero, which is not what MSSQL produces.

Comment: @Jez: see my updated answer, above.  The reality is that you probably shouldn't do this, especially not in security applications, as you are losing 75% of the hash during the conversion.

Comment: @Jez: I've stopped fiddling now!  The last version returned incorrect results where the value should have been positive.  I think this version is optimal.